# C++ BHO - Writing to registry in protected mode - win 8?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to write to registry through my BHO using IE 11 protected mode, it seems that only if I uncheck the protected mode in IE everything runs OK.
I
 tried writing to 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\LowRegistry' but it seems that it doesn't help in Win 8.

Is there a way to still write to registry with these settings?

Comment: no, that's the WHOLE POINT of protected mode.

Comment: I thought that the `LowRegistry` key was here to allow Protected Mode IE processes to use the registry, in a way comparable to the `AppData\LocalLow` disk directory. Could you post some minimal code and report failure code from the APIs?

Comment: @Mgetz The WHOLE POINT of the `AppData\LocalLow` disk directory is to allow protected mode processes to write to the disk. Works fine with IE9 in "protected mode" on Windows Seven.